# Rails Server not working - something to do with sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, rubygems, sprockets

I was able to run the command `rails s` fine all morning, then I uninstalled a couple of sprocket gems `sprocket-rails' and 'sprockets' (I think), however now I am getting the following error whenever I try to run the rails local server. I have tried reinstalling the gems and updated bundle. Under the error, I have included my list of gems. Many thanks

[image]

```html
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.0.0)
actionmailer (5.0.0)
actionpack (5.0.0)
actionview (5.0.0)
activejob (5.0.0)
activemodel (5.0.0)
activerecord (5.0.0)
activesupport (5.0.0, 4.2.6)
addressable (2.4.0)
arel (7.1.0, 7.0.0)
ast (2.3.0, 2.1.0)
astrolabe (1.3.1)
autoprefixer-rails (6.3.7)
bcrypt (3.1.11)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.6, 3.2.0.2)
bootstrap_form (2.4.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.12.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
byebug (9.0.5, 6.0.2)
capybara (2.7.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.4)
childprocess (0.5.9)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.8)
coderay (1.1.1)
coffee-rails (4.2.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
coveralls (0.8.13, 0.8.2)
cucumber (2.1.0)
cucumber-core (1.3.0)
data_mapper (1.2.0)
data_objects (0.10.17)
database_cleaner (1.5.3)
datamapper (1.2.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
devise (4.2.0)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
dm-aggregates (1.2.0)
dm-constraints (1.2.0)
dm-core (1.2.1)
dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-migrations (1.2.0)
dm-postgres-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-serializer (1.2.2)
dm-timestamps (1.2.0)
dm-transactions (1.2.0)
dm-types (1.2.2)
dm-validations (1.2.0)
do_postgres (0.10.17)
docile (1.1.5)
domain_name (0.5.24)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
extlib (0.9.16)
factory_girl (4.7.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.7.0)
faraday (0.9.2)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
ffi (1.9.14, 1.9.13, 1.9.10)
font-awesome-sass (4.6.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
gherkin3 (3.1.1)
globalid (0.3.6)
hashie (3.4.4)
highline (1.7.8)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
hub (1.12.4)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
jbuilder (2.6.0, 2.5.0)
jquery-rails (4.1.1)
json (1.8.3)
json_pure (1.8.3)
jwt (1.5.4)
libv8 (3.16.14.15 x86_64-darwin-15)
listen (3.0.8)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mimemagic (0.3.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0, 2.0.0)
minitest (5.9.0, 5.8.3)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.11.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
netrc (0.10.3)
nio4r (1.2.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8, 1.6.7.2, 1.6.6.2)
oauth2 (1.2.0)
omniauth (1.3.1)
omniauth-facebook (3.0.0)
omniauth-github (1.1.2)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paperclip (5.0.0)
parser (2.3.1.2, 2.2.2.6)
pg (0.18.4)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
power_assert (0.2.6)
powerpack (0.1.1)
pry (0.10.3)
psych (2.0.17)
puma (3.5.2, 3.5.0, 3.4.0)
rack (2.0.1, 1.6.4)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (5.0.0)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.1)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.0.0)
rainbow (2.1.0, 2.0.0)
rake (11.2.2, 11.1.2, 10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rdoc (4.2.1)
ref (2.0.0)
responders (2.2.0)
rest-client (1.8.0)
rspec (3.4.0, 3.3.0)
rspec-collection_matchers (1.1.2)
rspec-core (3.5.1, 3.4.4, 3.3.2)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0, 3.4.0, 3.3.1)
rspec-json_expectations (1.4.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0, 3.4.1, 3.3.2)
rspec-rails (3.5.1)
rspec-sinatra (0.1.2)
rspec-support (3.5.0, 3.4.1, 3.3.0)
rubocop (0.40.0, 0.34.1)
rubocop-rspec (1.5.0, 1.3.1)
ruby-progressbar (1.8.1, 1.7.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.2.0)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.4.22)
sass-rails (5.0.5)
seeing_is_believing (3.0.0.beta.7, 2.2.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.53.0)
shotgun (0.9.1)
shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
simple_form (3.2.1)
simplecov (0.11.2, 0.10.0)
simplecov-html (0.10.0)
sinatra (1.4.7, 1.4.6)
sinatra-flash (0.3.0)
sinatra-partial (1.0.0)
slop (3.6.0)
spring (1.7.2)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.0)
sprockets (3.7.0, 3.6.3)
sprockets-rails (3.1.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
stringex (1.5.1)
templater (1.0.0)
term-ansicolor (1.3.2)
test-unit (3.1.5)
therubyracer (0.12.2)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.5, 2.0.1)
tins (1.6.0)
turbolinks (5.0.0)
turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
twilio-ruby (4.11.1)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uglifier (3.0.0)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
unicode-display_width (1.0.5)
uuidtools (2.1.5)
warden (1.2.6)
web-console (3.3.1)
websocket (1.2.3)
websocket-driver (0.6.4)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

Comment: sprockets is already included in rails default gemfile. You don't need to add anything. Anyway it's a warning.

Comment: the rails server immediately exits and I can not run anything in the browser?